# youtube-ios-player-helper: Embedded video doesn't increase view count

Tags: ios, swift, youtube-api, youtube-ios-player-helper

We are showing YouTube videos in our app with the youtube-ios-player-helper framework, but views that are being watch (disabled autoplay) is not shown up in YouTube analytics.

Is this by design, or have am I missing something?

Thanks